# How to reload a specific table from schema file in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Somehow, one of my tables has become divorced from the schema file.  In development, this isn't an issue, I could just drop the DB and reload it.

Unfortunately, it *is* an issue when the disconnect is somehow on production.  How can I mark a single table as needing to be reloaded from the schema, without damaging any other tables in the DB?

Answer (score 0):

What I found wounding up working was to create a pair of migrations, one dropping the table in question and the next reloading it.  It's not a perfect solution, but it worked well enough to continue development.

I strongly suspect user error in how the situation came about in the first place.